# Which plugin to use for the slider?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider

I need to make a slider. They say that you need to use the plugin, but I don’t know which one is suitable for my slider.Tell me, please, which plugin can I use to get such a slider like in the picture? I really need your help

```
[1]:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT5NC.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Revolution Slider. It is one of the best slider plugins available online. Here is the link for that https://revolution.themepunch.com/